# javascript Underscore nested loop undefined values

Tags: javascript, loops, backbone.js, for-loop, underscore.js

Let's say I have a collection of collections named, **collections**. Now, let's consider this piece of code.

```
_.each(collections, function(collection){
        _.each(collection, function(item){
           console.log(item);
        }
});
```

Several times, it prints undefined values. It seems to print item values before actually setting it from the previous loop. Why is it not retaining the order of execution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are in the collections? The implementation of _.each shouldn't give that behaviour.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so can you mark the correct one as answered. If not, can you clarify where you still have questions?

Answer (score 1):

Are `collections` and `collection` plain arrays? Or are they `Backbone.Collection`s?

The behavior you’re describing is not a bug in underscore. It should be maintaining the order of execution as you expect. This is probably an issue with the data in the collection.

If you want to strip all undefined values from your collection before running `.each` you can use [`_.compact(array)`](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) (assuming they are plain javascript arrays)

```
_.each(_.compact(collections), function(collection){
    _.each(_.compact(collection), function(item){
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you're right about `collection` being a Backbone collection, in that case `collection.each(function(item) { ... })` would be the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is just because the inner loop also runs it's callback asynchronously. So the parent loop doesn't wait for it to complete, it runs straightaway the next iteration.

Comment: [underscore's `each` implementation](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-15) does not run it's callbacks asynchronously. It defaults to [the native `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if available.